# SOLR on load balance

Tags: solr, indexing

I have 2 CD instances. When I enable both the instances I get below error on website

`Index proj_web_index was not found.`

Although it works fine when only one instance is enabled.

Indexes are on Solr.

Please suggest

1. What could be the root cause of the error?
2. If we need to have 2 solr instances for each CD (or one instance on two port)? What is recommended setup?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70641/discussion-on-question-by-s-kazmi-solr-on-load-balance).

Comment: Are you using SolrCloud?

Comment: Was this fixed?